# Android, don't generate ActionBar

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-studio, android-actionbar

You can hide the action bar at runtime by calling `hide()`. For example:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

So it can be hidden after being generated. 
How to prevent it from being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a your activity's theme to one with no ActionBar. Check `.NoActionBar` in your current theme.

For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```